# Create Collection of type Class<T>

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I'm trying to write a function that given a class it will build an object of that type (using reflection). Its working so far but I'm having trouble with Collections as members.

```java
public static <T> T object(Class<T> type) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

            T object = getNullInstanceOf(type);

            List<Field> fields = Arrays.asList(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields());

            for (Field f : fields) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                if (Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers())) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    Object fieldValue = f.get(object);
                    if (f.getType().equals(CharSequence.class) || f.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                        f.set(object, f.getName());
                    } else if (f.getType().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
                        f.set(object, 1);
                    } else if (f.getType().equals(Double.TYPE)) {
                        f.set(object, 2.0);
                    } else if (f.getType().equals(Long.TYPE)) {
                        f.set(object, 3L);
                    } else if (isClassCollection(f.getType())) {
                        f.set(object,
                                ((Collection) getNullInstanceOf(f.getType())) // this throws a "No Such Method Exists" Exception
                                    .add(object(f.getGenericType().getClass()))); 
                    } else if (!(f.getType().equals(type))) {
                        f.set(object, object(f.getType()));
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Could not access:" + f.getName());
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return object;
        }

        public static boolean isClassCollection(Class<?> c) {
            return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(c)
                    || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(c);
        }

        private static <T> T getNullInstanceOf(Class<T> type) throws InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException,
                IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(type.getName());
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
            return (T) ctor.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that when I try to create an instance of the `Collection`, whether it be a `Set`, `List`, or `Map`, those classes are abstract. Is there a way to just pick a random implementation or do I have to hardcode a concrete subclass for every abstract class?

Comment: You will need to choose a concrete class.

Comment: What are you actually trying to acheive?

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to use `equals` for classes. Each `Class` in a unique object that is only equal to itself, so you can use `==`. You also don’t need fields like `Integer.TYPE`, you can get every `Class` for a known type uniformly using `type.class`, i.e. `int.class` instead of `Integer.TYPE`. So, you can use `if(f.getType() == int.class) f.setInt(object, 1);`. There’s also no reason to read the field when you never use that value. And you don’t need to wrap arrays in lists to iterate them. You can simply use `for(Field f: object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) { …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it seems like you are okay with any random implementation. If that **includes EMPTY IMMUTABLE implementation** as well, then you could make use of the `static` method `of`, which is available in `Map`, `List` and `Set`.

(Note that in `isClassCollection` you are checking for both `Map` and `Collection` and then in your current code, you were casting the result to `Collection`. This would fail when the input type is a `Map`. This is because `Map` is not a `Collection`)

```java
public static boolean isClassCollection(Class<?> c) {
    return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(c) || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(c);;
}
```

Now, the main change is to be done in your `getNullInstanceOf`

```java
private static <T> T getNullInstanceOf(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
    if(isClassCollection(clazz)) {
        return (T) clazz.getMethod("of").invoke(null);
    }
       
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(type.getName());
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    return (T) ctor.newInstance();
}
```

Now, slightly change the if condition in the `object` method as:

```java
else if (isClassCollection(f.getType())) {
    f.set(object, getNullInstanceOf(f.getType())); 
}
```

Comment: static interface methods are not inherited, so you can’t just call `getMethod("of")` on the actual type. Further, there are collections which are neither `Set` nor `List`. You have to determine which of the two cases, `List` or `Set`, applies. Then, you could do, e.g. `List.class.getMethod("of").invoke(null)` but there would be no point in doing so. Just call the method directly, `if(List.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) return List.of();` There’s also no point in the conditional type cast in the last snippet; `f.set(…)` expects `Object` anyway. The OP did cast to `Collection` to invoke `add`…

Comment: Though, if the field’s declared type is a concrete subtype of `List` or `Set`, you can’t use `List.of()` resp. `Set.of()` at all. So the cleanest approach would be `if(field.getType() == List.class) field.set(object, List.of());` etc, as that is the only case where it works.

Comment: @Holger By this statement -> "_so you can’t just call getMethod("of") on the actual type_", I assume you were pointing to the case when the field in the class is declared with a type which is an implementation of List or Set like `private ArrayList<String> list;`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It only occurred to me afterwards that it wouldn’t work anyway, as you can’t assign `List.of()` to such a field. That’s why I suggested to use `field.getType() == List.class` instead of `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())` in my second comment. When the field’s type is `Collection` (or even `Iterable`), you could use either `Set.of()` or `List.of()`, but you have to decide. Note that the OP wanted to add an element to it (but `f.getGenericType().getClass()` doesn’t do what they want), so you would have to use the one-arg version, but getting the element type is complicated

Comment: @Holger Yes I tried one solution using the generic type as `((ParameterizedType) genericType).getActualTypeArguments();` to add an element, but it gets complicated in choosing a constructor, when that class has no "no-args" constructor like `Integer`